# how i could remove placeholder when i focus on it ? (using pure javascript)

Tags: javascript

Could you give me some possible ways to delete an input's placeholder on focus and reset it again on blur ?

I tried that :

```
const input = document.getElementById('input');

// This code is for clear placeholder value
if(input.placeholder){
    input.addEventListener('focus' , (e) => {
        input.placeholder = '';
    });
}else {
    input.addEventListener( 'blur' , () => {
        input.placeholder = 'hi'
    });
};
```

the code I wrote works just fine on focus mode but I don't know how to reset the value on blur mode.

thank you in advance <3;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply:

```js
const input = document.getElementById('input');


input.onfocus = () =>
  {
  if (!input.placeholerValue) input.placeholerValue = input.placeholder
  input.placeholder = ''
  }
input.onblur = () =>
  {
  input.placeholder = input.placeholerValue 
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const input = document.getElementById('input');

// a variable to hold the placeholder value
let placeholderValue = ""

input.addEventListener('focus', (e) => {
  // saving the placeholder value in a variable
  placeholderValue = input.placeholder
  console.log("Saving", placeholderValue)

  // clearing the placeholder
  input.placeholder = '';
  console.log("Clearing!")
});

input.addEventListener('blur', () => {
  // restoring the placeholder from the variable
  input.placeholder = placeholderValue
  console.log("Restoring", placeholderValue)
});
```

```html
<input id="input" type="text" placeholder="whatever">
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
Try if want single-line solution for it

<input id="input" type="text" onfocus="this.placeholder=''" onblur="this.placeholder= this.getAttribute('data-placeholder')" data-placeholder="whatever" placeholder="whatever" value="">
```